# Grabbing values from select list

Tags: oracle-apex

i have a select list displaying all the names from the table X
i want to add id of that corresponding name in to another table naming Y. 
HOW TO GRAB VALUE FROM SELECT LIST AND STORE IT IN TO DATABASE TABLE???

Answer (score 0):

A list of values doesn't depend on *anything*; you can write any query you want (which includes your table X), as long as it returns two values: *display* and *return* ones. For example:

```
select name display_value,
       id   return_value
from table_x
where <some condition, if there's any>
order by name
```

If you create a form page and make its source table Y, choose which one of the columns should contain an ID returned by the Select List item and put the above query into its LoV property.

- Run the page;
- choose a value from the Select List;
- Submit

Should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an Apex process to perform your desired action, like store the value in your database.

Once your user selects a value from your LOV, usually you'll want to submit the page, which you would tell to run that process.

Alternately, you could create a Dynamic Action on the LOV that runs a PL/SQL process to do your database change.

*You may have gotten an answer by now but I thought I'd take a swing at it. I'm trying to get my reputation over the next threshold. :-)*

Comment: Yeah I got it. Thanks